# How does one get the values from the inner classes of deserialized JSON?

Tags: json, vb.net, google-maps

I am trying to get the lat and lng values from the Google Geocode API.  I set up the classes using a vb translation of [parse google maps geocode json response to object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001132/682480).  I can access the status, and the top level result, but I cannot seem to access the children of result, even though the data shows up in debug mode when I hover over result and open up the plus signs.

How does one get the values from the inner classes of deserialized json?
Lines setting decLat and decLon say "geometry is not a member of Systems.Array"

```
Dim result = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(Request.ToString)
                        Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of GoogleGeoCodeResponse)(result)
                        If Response.status = "OK" Then
                            decLat = Response.results.geometry.location.lat
                            decLon = Response.results.geometry.location.lng



 Public Class GoogleGeoCodeResponse

        Public Property status() As String
            Get
                Return m_status
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_status = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_status As String
        Public Property results() As results()
            Get
                Return m_results
            End Get
            Set(value As results())
                m_results = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_results As results()

    End Class

    Public Class results
        Public Property formatted_address() As String
            Get
                Return m_formatted_address
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_formatted_address = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_formatted_address As String
        Public Property geometry() As Geometry
            Get
                Return m_geometry
            End Get
            Set(value As Geometry)
                m_geometry = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_geometry As Geometry
        Public Property types() As String()
            Get
                Return m_types
            End Get
            Set(value As String())
                m_types = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_types As String()
        Public Property address_components() As address_component()
            Get
                Return m_address_components
            End Get
            Set(value As address_component())
                m_address_components = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_address_components As address_component()
    End Class

    Public Class geometry
        Public Property location_type() As String
            Get
                Return m_location_type
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_location_type = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_location_type As String
        Public Property location() As location
            Get
                Return m_location
            End Get
            Set(value As location)
                m_location = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_location As location
    End Class

    Public Class location
        Public Property lat() As Decimal
            Get
                Return m_lat
            End Get
            Set(value As Decimal)
                m_lat = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_lat As String
        Public Property lng() As Decimal
            Get
                Return m_lng
            End Get
            Set(value As Decimal)
                m_lng = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_lng As String
    End Class

    Public Class address_component
        Public Property long_name() As String
            Get
                Return m_long_name
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_long_name = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_long_name As String
        Public Property short_name() As String
            Get
                Return m_short_name
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_short_name = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_short_name As String
        Public Property types() As String()
            Get
                Return m_types
            End Get
            Set(value As String())
                m_types = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_types As String()
    End Class
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code that is failing?

Comment: It isn't an error, it is that the children of result do not show up in intellisense.

Comment: code has been added.  Thanks

Comment: Seems like you simply need to cast the results as the correct object type.

Comment: figured it out:decLat = Response.results(0).geometry.location.lat
                            decLon = Response.results(0).geometry.location.lng