# Pick out value from Json

Tags: c#, json

I have this code for working with GoogleMapsApi:

```
 public void GoogleGeoCode(string address)
        {
            address = "Stockholm";
            string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";

            dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + address).GetDynamicJsonObject();

            //Code that lets me pick out values from googleresults

        }
```

googleresults contains values (longitude/latitude) but how can i pich those out and use the for something else?  I used this approach in a similar situation but it is not valid code in this case:

```
 JObject o = JObject.Parse(googleresult);

 string name = (string)o.SelectToken("longitude");
```

EDIT:

This seems to pick put the longitude and latitude:

```
public void GoogleGeoCode(string address)
        {
            address = "Stockholm";
            string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";

            dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + address).GetDynamicJsonObject();


            foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
            {

                double lng = result.geometry.location.lng;

                double  lat  = result.geometry.location.lat;
            }

            //Do something else...

        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse google maps geocode json response to object using Json.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001132/parse-google-maps-geocode-json-response-to-object-using-json-net)

Comment: Have you thought about deserializing into an object instead, then accessing it via that object using dot notation?

Comment: @mason, do you mind elaborating on how to do that?

Comment: Well, first you generate a C# class that you can deserialize into. [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) is good for that. Then you simply deserialize it into that object, if you were using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) you'd use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` method.

Comment: Thank you Mason, I can see this to be useful to try in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your googleResults is not a string.  It is a dynamic jason object.  Try looking at this.

Code from here: [Looking for a REST with JSON client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389420/looking-for-a-rest-with-json-client-library)

```
public static void GoogleGeoCode(string address)
{
    string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";
    dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url + address).GetDynamicJsonObject();

    foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + result.geometry.location.lat + "," + 
                            result.geometry.location.lng + "] " + 
                            result.formatted_address);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but no "properties" shows up when i write o., thank you.

Comment: How do you mean "put a watch on"?

Comment: No its an MVC project with c#.

Comment: Please look at revised answer.  Sorry I took you down the wrong path.  Good luck!

Comment: No problem, thank you for takig the time. However, my error occurs on this line:
JObject o = JObject.Parse(googleresults);
The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Please see revised answer.  Hope it helps more.

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work with your help. I also added the new code in my question. Thank you for your time!