# Trying to separate two separate strings

Tags: c#, json.net, geojson.net

I'm trying to return to separate string in this if statement and not as a single string. one as a latitude and the other as longitude

```
static string GeoCoding(string address)
{
    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(baseUrlGC + address.Replace(" ", "+")
        + plusUrl);//concatenate URL with the input address and downloads the requested resource
    GoogleGeoCodeResponse jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(json); //deserializing the result to GoogleGeoCodeResponse

    string status = jsonResult.status; // get status 

    string geoLocation = String.Empty;

    //check if status is OK
    if (status == "OK") 
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonResult.results.Length;i++) //loop throught the result for lat/lng
        {
            geoLocation = jsonResult.results[i].geometry.location.lat + jsonResult.results[i].geometry.location.lng + Environment.NewLine; //append the result addresses to every new line
        }
        return geoLocation; //return result
    }
    else
    {
        return status; //return status / error if not OK
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Your loop assigns a brand new value to `geoLocation` every time so you'll only get the last string. Perhaps you wanted `geoLocation = geoLocation + ...`

Comment: @PeterCsala I'm to separate into two and return each value differently. Eg Latitude = jsonResult.results[i].geometry.location.lat and Longitude = jsonResult.results[i].geometry.location.lng

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parse google maps geocode json response to object using Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001132/parse-google-maps-geocode-json-response-to-object-using-json-net)

Comment: Then change the signature to return a `ValueTuple`: `static (string Latitude, string Longitude) GeoCoding(string address)` and change the `return` statements as well accordingly.

Comment: The old way would be to create a class or struct with properties for latitude and longitude and return that. But maybe you would like to return it as a JSON-string? You could serialize the class or struct to JSON in that case. But a newer way would be to return a tuple:  (string long, string lat) GeoCoding(string address)

Comment: @PeterCsala do you mind doing it because I am a bit confused

Comment: @Musty Do you want to return a single lat-long pair or do you need all lat-long pairs? If the status code is not okay then is it fine from requirement perspective to throw an exception?

Comment: @PeterCsala i want all lat-long pairs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your expected result is 2 string:
Latitude
Longitude
and a code when there is error.
I would suggest you create a new

```
class GeoResponse{
List<(string, string)> geocodeList;
string  status;
}
```

and change return type of your method to

```
static GeoResponse GeoCoding(string address)
        {
            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(baseUrlGC + address.Replace(" ", "+")
                + plusUrl);//concatenate URL with the input address and downloads the requested resource
            GoogleGeoCodeResponse jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(json); //deserializing the result to GoogleGeoCodeResponse

           

            GeoResponse result = new GeoResponse();
            result.status = jsonResult.status; // get status 

            //check if status is OK
            if (status == "OK")
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonResult.results.Length; i++) //loop throught the result for lat/lng
                {
                    result.geocodeList.Add(jsonResult.results[i].geometry.location.lat, jsonResult.results[i].geometry.location.lng);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to return with all lat-long pairs (without creating a new data structure) when `status` is `ok` and throw an exception when `status` was not `ok` then you can do that like this:

```
static List<Tuple<string, string>> GeoCoding(string address)
{
    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString($"...");
    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(json); 

    if (jsonResult.status != "OK")
        throw new Exception($"Request failed with {jsonResult.status}");

    return jsonResult.results
        .Select(result => result.geometry.location)
        .Select(loc => new Tuple<string, string>(loc.lat, loc.lng))
        .ToList();
}
```

If you can use `ValueTuple` then you could rewrite the code like this:

```
static List<(string Lat, string Long)> GeoCoding(string address)
{
    ...

    return jsonResult.results
        .Select(result => result.geometry.location)
        .Select(loc => (loc.lat, loc.lng))
        .ToList();
}
```

Please also note that `WebClient` is deprecated so please prefer `HttpClient` instead.

---

**UPDATE #1**

> I want to output "N/A" for the ZERO_RESULTS

```
static List<(string Lat, string Long)> GeoCoding(string address)
{
    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString($"...");
    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(json); 

    if (jsonResult.status == "ZERO_RESULTS")
        return new List<(string, string)> { ("N/A", "N/A") };

    if (jsonResult.status != "OK")
        throw new Exception($"Request failed with {jsonResult.status}");

    return jsonResult.results
        .Select(result => result.geometry.location)
        .Select(loc => (loc.lat, loc.lng))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly but the problem is that there's an exception unhandled error saying "System.Exception: 'Request failed with ZERO_RESULTS' "

Comment: @Musty You should receive that exception only if the parsed json's `status` contains different string than `"OK"`.  If `ZERO_RESULTS` should be treated as an empty list then you should code that inside the `GeoCoding` method.

Comment: Yes i want to output "N/A" for the ZERO_RESULTS. Should i use an if statement for it. similar to the ok statement?

Comment: @Musty Yes, you can handle that with branching.

Comment: I tried the branching but i am still getting the same error

Comment: @Musty Let me amend my post to include this as well.

Comment: @Musty I've just did it, please check it!

Comment: I used the WebClient so i get an error

Comment: @Musty I'm not sure what do mean. The IDE warns you that it is deprecated, but that's just a warning not error (unless you specified your project to [treat warnings as error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings))

Comment: I can't run the program because I get an error not warning

Comment: @Musty What error do you receive?

Comment: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(string, string)>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<string, string>>

Comment: @Musty I think you are mixing the two proposed solutions. If you are using `Tuple` not `ValueTuple` then the *update #1* should use this code: `return new List<Tuple<string, string>> { new Tuple<string, string>("N/A", "N/A") };`

Comment: Yes I was mixing it up. I tried your new solution but it prints out nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248570/discussion-between-peter-csala-and-musty).